# develop mobile application using mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile-application

I need to develop a mobile application using mvc3 for capturing images from camera, but actually i dont have any idea about mobile app development, can we develop mobile app using mvc3, i dont want to use mvc4 also any suggestions about how to get started with mobile apps?

Comment: You might want to check this out http://xamarin.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is a framework for developing **web applications** based on the .NET framework. A web application usually ends up spitting HTML to the client. You could use a javascript framework such as [`jQuery Mobile`](http://jquerymobile.com/) for example in order to create mobile friendly content. You could have used it with any server side framework, not only ASP.NET MVC.

But you will never be able to develop a native mobile application running on a mobile phone using a server side framework.